# Access Data from First recordset

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ query that returns a few rows.  It has a join so that it includes company contact information along with the detail records (so the contact info is repeated for every row).  On my view page I wish to display the contact info in a header area only once and then loop through the recordset to display the detail data.

How do I access the contact data in the first record without looping?

Is there a better approach?  I was avoiding stuffing all the contact fields into ViewBag variables as I thought it would be more correct to grab them with a single DB query.

BTW What is the trick to getting the code blocks to work in here.  I always click the code button and then paste my code directly from VS.  Sometimes the color formatting works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.CompanyName)
    </div>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Address1)
    </div>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.City)
    </div>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.State)
    </div>
    <div class="view-field">
        @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Zip)
    </fieldset>


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusUserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusNote)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

**EDIT**
Working with Boossss idea, I came up with this LINQ and ViewModel but they are not quite getting me a solution that works. I get a single recordset with a subcollection of VendorStatusHistory records which is exactly what I want, it throws error trying to display any property of the viewmodel "does not contain a definition... and no extension method... could be found."  I tried using Boossss viewmodel but it gave same error.  I suspect my LINQ query is off.

**SOLVED**
Updated based on Boossss comments.

```
     public StatusHistoryView VendorStatusHistory(String id)
    {
        Guid pid = Guid.Parse(id);

        StatusHistoryView query = _db.VendorProfiles 
            .Include("VendorStatusHistory")
            .Include("StatusCodes")
            .Select(s => new StatusHistoryView
                {
                    ProfileID = s.ProfileID,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                    CompanyDBA = s.CompanyDBA,
                    Email = s.Email,
                    Phone = s.Phone,
                    Website = s.Website,
                    Address1 = s.Address1,
                    Address2 = s.Address2,
                    City = s.City,
                    State = s.State,
                    Zip = s.Zip,
                    VendorStatusHistory = s.VendorStatusHistories
                }
            )
            .Where(x => x.ProfileID == pid).SingleOrDefault();;

         return query;
    }

public class StatusHistoryView
{
    public StatusHistoryView()
    {
        this.VendorStatusHistory = new HashSet<VendorStatusHistory>();
    }
    public System.Guid ProfileID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DBA")]
    public string CompanyDBA { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address (extra)")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VendorStatusHistory> VendorStatusHistory { get; set; }
}
```

and the updated view...

```
            @model  VendorProfileIntranet.Models.StatusHistoryView

<table id="VendorTable" width="100%" class="gradeA">
    <thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model.VendorStatusHistory)
        {
        <tr>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.DateCreated)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.Status)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => item.Notes)
            </th>
        </tr>
            break;
            }
    </thead>
    <tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model.VendorStatusHistory )
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusUserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusNote)
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Found one solution is to wrap the contact info in foreach and include a break statement so it only loops once.  Hoping someone can suggest a more elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you didn't join the company contact information along with the detail records, instead create a viewmodel and pass it as your view's model like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public List<RecordDetail> Records { get; set; }
}

public class RecordDetail
{
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string StatusUserName { get; set; }
    public string StatusNote { get; set; }
}
```

after this you can use it in your view like this:

```
@model MyViewModel
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.CompanyName)
</div>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Address1)
</div>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.City)
</div>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.State)
</div>
<div class="view-field">
    @Html.ValueFor(m => m.Zip)
</fieldset>


    @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusUserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StatusNote)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Thx, this is the direction I was looking for, however cannot get the right LINQ query and ViewModel to make it work (see above)

Comment: Hi Vic, your viewmodel looks fine :), but what is the model that you are passing into the view? are you passing an IEnumerable<StatusHistoryView> or a StatusHistoryView? You should be passing a single StatusHistoryView.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I overlooked that and removed IEnumerable from LINQ and view page and added the SingleOrDefault to the LINQ.  This got everything displaying. However, that left me with one more problem in displaying the heading labels for the rows of VendorStatusHistory.  In order to get the headings to display, I had to resort back to the single foreach with a break (see update in OP) - not elegant but it got me 99.9% there.